# About Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs, one on side of the other, and when I restore the screen-size, arrive a point where the divs are overlaid. One div is a side menu, and is positinate on the left of browser-screen; it have 12% of width. The other div is with 12% of margin-left. What I need do for they don't be overlaid?
Since of already, thanks you!

Part of the code:

```
     #header{
        background: #DEDEDE;
        color: #e20074;
        width: 88%;
        font-family: serif;
        margin-left: 12%;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
     #menu{
    margin-top: -30px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 12%;
    height: 88%;
    float:  none;
  }
<div id="header" class="jumbotron">
    <h4 id="title">
    {{app}}
    </h4>
</body>
</div>
  <div id="menu" class="jumbotron">
      <hm>Menu</h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more as I can't understand what you are after?

Comment: Andrew, sorry for don't be more course. What I want say is that when I restore the screen-size, the divs are overlaid, one rises on the top of other. What I should make for the divs continues responsive, but don't rises on the top of the other? The header div is with 12% of margin-left, and these 12%, on maximize screen-browser, is the space that the Menu width occupies, but when I reduce the screen-size, the margin-left of header stays with less 12% of distance, and overlaid the Menu.

You managed to understand-me now?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the width of the `#header`, the `#menu` and the margin exceeds the 100% width:

88% + 12% + 12% = 112%

Try changing the `width` of #header to `76%` so the total width adds up to 100% as you can see below:

76% + 12% + 12% = 100%

If you don't want the header width to be too small, you will either have to reduce the margin or the menu width so the total equals **100%**

```
#header {
    width: 76%;
    /* other style properties */
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but don't was work. 88% of the view are occupied by the Header width, and the other 12% are occupied by the Menu width. My problem is the header that change your width for more of that 88%, and occupied the menu space. :/

Comment: Can you please post a microsoft paint sketch showing what the site looks like now and how you want it to look?

Comment: When browser the is on full-size, all is work, this just happens when I change the browser-size for less.